# Suppose $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and the quotient group $G/H$ has order $n$. Prove that for every $g$ in $G$, $g^n\in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and the quotient
>   group $G/H$ has order $n$. Prove that for every $g$ in $G$, $g^n\in
>  H$.

I just cannot see any way to go about this question. I keep messing around and writing a bunch of stuff down that's getting me absolutely nowhere.

Thank you

Comment: $\bar{g}^n=e$ in $G/H$ since $G/H$ has order $n$, and $\bar{g}^n=\overline{g^n}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g \in G$. Consider $gH$ as element of the group $G/H$. By Lagranges theorem, $(gH)^{n} = Id_{G/H}$, hence $g^{n}H=H$, so $g^{n} \in H$

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm an idiot, this was an easy question..

Answer (score 3):

For all $g\in G$, $g^{n}H=(gH)^{n}=H$. Thus $g^{n}\in H$.

Comment: Thank you, this was such an easy question, a bit annoyed at myself actually.